# Running a WHILE when using mysqli instead of mysql.

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do this with mysqli. Until now to stop the code reading the next line I have been adding 9999 to $i.
($num_vmbd is the number of rows.)

```
while ($i < $num_vmbd){
    $vmb_avg = mysql_result($vmbdtbd,$i,"vmb_avg");
    $vmb_par = mysql_result($vmbdtbd,$i,"vmb_par");
    $vmb_total = $vmb_total + $vmb_avg;
    if ($vmb_par == "harry"){
        $i = $i + 9999; // 
    } 
$i++;
}
```

It adds a corresponding value for each row in turn, when it finds the value of "harry" it no longer reads in any more lines ($num_vmbd is never more than about 30 so by adding 9999 to $i it stops the while statement. How do I go about coverting this to mysqli?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if ($vmb_par == "harry") break;`

Comment: You should be looking at PDO, not mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have changed the rest of your code to `mysqli` as well, something like this is probably what you want (I'm assuming your db connection is in `$conn`, and your query string in `$sql`):

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $vmb_avg = $row["vmb_avg"];
    $vmb_par = $row["vmb_par"]);
    $vmb_total = $vmb_total + $vmb_avg;
    if ($vmb_par == "harry") break;
}
```